# Joining a CSV file to query results

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query written to read in a `.csv` file:

```
var csv =
    from line in File.ReadAllLines("C:/file.csv")
    let customerRecord = line.Split(',')
    select new Customer()
        {
            contactID = customerRecord[0],
            surveyDate = customerRecord[1],
            project = customerRecord[2],
            projectCode = customerRecord[3]
        };
```

From here, I'd like to inner join this data on `contactID` to another query:

```
var prods = 
    from prd in products
    join con in contacts
    on prd.PrimaryContact equals con.ContactID
    select new {createdDate = prd.CreatedDate, contactID = con.ContactID};
```

I'm new to linq, and would like to know how I can join the data from csv to prods on the contactID field.

Thank you for your help in advance, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Would inserting the CSV data into the database be an option? Using CSV files as anything other than a user input method should be considered a smell IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not.  What I'm doing is taking some data from our marketing automation tool and trying to tie it to data from our production environment.  In a perfect world this data would all be housed on the same SQL server, but it's not, and I don't have control over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I think I have it.

```
var merged = from cr in csv
  join pr in prods
  on cr.contactID equals pr.contactID
  select new{
    cr.contactID,
    cr.surveyDate,
    cr.project,
    cr.projectCode,
    pr.createdDate};
```

I'm assuming both have string `contactID`. If not, then you need to cast one way or the other.

Comment: The data in prods is coming from a SQL server where I work.  When I try to join as you did above, I get an error:  Cannot execute text selection: The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Comment: That didn't fix it, but I'm starting to think it is a variable type mismatch.  contactID in the SQL database is INT32.  Should I need to explicitly tell linq that contactID from the .csv file is of that type?

Comment: Yes. `cr.contactID equals pr.contactID.ToString()` or have `contactID` as an int in the first place if they're going to join (parse the int in the select that creates it). That totally explains the issue.

Comment: Ok, I got everything to work Jon.  I really appreciate your help.  As I said, I'm very new (this week) to linq and while I have a decent background in C# and SQL I've never pushed the two together.

Comment: Was it just the cast alone, or did it also need the `AsEnumerable()` added?

Comment: You can pull the AsEnumerable() from your solution, and place a comma after cr.projectCode if you'd like to have the clean version.

Comment: Cool. BTW, the `AsEnumerable()` was there because it's sometimes necessary to force something that doesn't work (or doesn't work well) in the DB to be done in memory. It's one of those things that's a bad idea except when it's an absolutely great idea. The missing comma was just a typo.

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend you profile this query as I suspect you are now fetching way too many records into memory (due to the AsEnumerable call). You may want to look at filtering the prods using the .Contains extension method as long as the number of records in your CSV are realistic (< 1000 rows max).